# Mongoose Save Callback is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm building a server for a simple web app that uses a MongoDB backend for storing data. I instantiate a new mongoose connection using:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/callback-newsfeed-db')
```

My MongoDB output seems fine:

```
2017-12-02T21:00:53.277-0800 I NETWORK  [thread1] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:52027 #86 (1 connection now open)
2017-12-02T21:00:53.291-0800 I NETWORK  [thread1] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:52028 #87 (2 connections now open)
2017-12-02T21:00:53.291-0800 I NETWORK  [thread1] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:52029 #88 (3 connections now open)
2017-12-02T21:00:53.292-0800 I NETWORK  [thread1] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:52030 #89 (4 connections now open)
2017-12-02T21:00:53.292-0800 I NETWORK  [thread1] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:52031 #90 (5 connections now open)
```

I also defined a Model as follows:

```
const postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  api: String,
  source: String,
  title: String,
  upvotes: Number
})

const Post = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema)
```

In one of my server endpoints, I have the following code:

```
server.post('/posts', (request, response) => {
  console.log("INSIDE POSTS POST")
  const newapi = request.body.api
  const newsource = request.body.source
  const newtitle = request.body.title

  if(!newapi){
    response.send(422, "MUST PROVIDE API TYPE")
    return
  }else if(!newsource){
    response.send(422, "MUST PROVIDE RESOURCE SOURCE")
    return
  }else if(!newtitle){
    response.send(422, "MUST PROVIDE RESOURCE TITLE")
    return
 }

// Add a new post
  const newPost = new post.Post({
      api: newapi,
      source: newsource,
      title: newtitle,
      upvotes: UPVOTE_DEFAULT
  })
  console.log("ABOUT TO SAVE")

  // Save to DB and send to client
  newPost.save(error => {
      console.log("SAVE ERROR " )
      console.log(error)
      if(error){
          console.log("ERROR IN NEWPOST")
          throw error
      }else{
          console.log("STATUS OK")
          response.status(STATUS_OK)
          response.set({'Content-type': 'application/json'})
          response.send(JSON.stringify(newPost))
      }
      console.log("SAVE HAS COMPLETED")
  })
  console.log("AFTER NEW POST")
  })
```

Now when I run my app, I see the following output in the console:

```
INSIDE POSTS POST
ABOUT TO SAVE
AFTER NEW POST
```

However, for some reason (regardless of how long I wait) no part of the newPost.save() callback ever seems to get called.  The MongoDB output doesn't indicate an obvious error, so I'm a bit lost. Why could that be happening?

I'm pretty new to node so any thoughts on how to even go about debugging this or thinking about possible bug culprits would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue appears to have been an incompatibility between the version of MongoDB I was using and mongoose. Once I upgraded my mongodb version via a call to npm upgrade mongodb, the save operation appears to have started working

Answer (score 2):

You could set mongoose to use ES6 Promises.

```
  mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
  mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI);
```

Then you can use

```
  newPost.save().then( () => {
    console.log('Everything went well');
  }).catch( (e) => {
    console.log('There was an error', e.message);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const newPost = new post.Post({
```

Should be

```
const newPost = new Post({
```

Comment: I actually already have console.log statements within every branch of the callback as you can see above, and none of it is getting printed.